# How to publish AsyncApi in github-pages like swagger-github-pages?

Tags: swagger, asyncapi

I want to know how to publish (if possible) an [AsyncApi](https://playground.asyncapi.io/) project in github pages like We do with  [swagger-github-pages](https://github.com/peter-evans/swagger-github-pages).

My final goal is to have an AsyncApi documentation like the [Swagger Petstore](https://petstore.swagger.io/) example available for the consumers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [generator with the HTML template](https://www.asyncapi.com/generator) provided by the AsyncAPI community.

Basically it's produced an `intex.html` file from your AsyncAPI document. You could then publish this `intex.html` in the same way like described in [swagger-github-pages](https://github.com/peter-evans/swagger-github-pages).